# Programmatically Connect domains to servers

Tags: dns, virtualhost, web-hosting, cloudflare, godaddy-api

I want to create a simple web app. where user can have a form to add domain and directory name( that is already created on our server ). And it simply starts pointing the domain to that directory. What apis should I need for this? Hosting and domains can be bought from same brand, like GoDady.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare has an [API to add DNS records](https://api.cloudflare.com/#dns-records-for-a-zone-create-dns-record).
However, if you go this route, these are the prerequisites:

1. User's domain must already be activated in Cloudflare. At least partial-setup with Cloudflare's hosting partner (Siteground etc which have Cloudflare integrations built-in) or full-setup (the domain's authoritative nameserver points to Cloudflare).
2. User must trust you with their email address linked to their Cloudflare account and their Global API key.

Your web app can then make the API call to the endpoint and Cloudflare will create the appropriate DNS records to point to your server.

Comment: What about goDaddy? Like if the users buys the domain from godday, and we have hosted the app also on goddady?

Comment: Cloudflare only manage the DNS so it can work with GoDaddy or any other domain registrars and hosting providers out there. If your solution is GoDaddy-centric, I believe they have an API to manage the DNS records too: https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains

Comment: For example I have a server having Base , D1 and D2 as directories.Base has a form, where as a user you enter www.d1.com and D1, What Base does is redirect domain to D1. Simple is that. Now What should I do to solve this problem? What will be the issues. I mean we can restrict users to buy domains from that providers where our app is hosted. Or we can buy the domains for them too.